# How to return boolean in if else statement and the return value will link to anothe if else statement in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, if-statement

I have the following if else statement that created by myself in order to link to the if else statement given in second part:

```
m=4
if m==3
   disp(true)
else
   disp(false)
```

Second part ( this code is fix cannot be change):

```
if (true)
   A=Hello World
else
   A=Bye
```

If using the first part code, my output will be

```
A=Hello World
```

**but my desire output is**

```
A=Bye
```

Anyone one have idea to edit the first part, because now my return value in first part not able to link to my second part.

Comment: @SardarUsama hi my desire result is A=Bye

Comment: Do you want to change the first code to produce the output of the second?

Comment: yes, I need change the first part code

Comment: Is all you want:`A='Hello World'` after `disp(true)` and `A='Bye'` after `disp(false)`?

Comment: @SardarUsama yes , you are right, but I not able to change the second part code, so only first part can be edited

Comment: and I am also suggesting you to edit the first code exactly how I showed in the previous comment. tbh you need to completely get rid of the second part. It is using a forever true statement in `if`, it is  buggy and cannot be fixed without overshadowing `true` which indeed is a bad practice

Comment: @SardarUsama I can't see your previous comment that you show

Comment: You can definitely see. It is still there and not deleted

Comment: @SardarUsama sorry really cannot see here

Comment: Are you even serious? Is this a troll? Write `A='Hello World'` after `disp(true)` and `A='Bye'` after `disp(false)` and get rid of your second code

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the second part's code, I'm afraid your desire cannot be fulfilled. Or rather, I'm afraid your code won't run at all, because your perenthesis, quotes, end-statement (and arguably semicolons) are not in place.

```
if true
    A = 'Hello World';
else
    A = 'Bye';
end
```

This code will return `A = 'Hello World'`, no matter what, since true is always true. If-else conditions work like this:

```
if (*what's in here evealuates to true*)  
%do stuff
else (*if what's up there does not evaluate to true*)
%do other stuff
```

Clearly, `true` will always evaluate to `true`. So the above if-else condition will always return `A = 'Hello World'`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two `if statements` in order to accomplish this task. One is more than enough to perform all what you need:

```
m = 4;

if (m == 3)
   A = 'Hello World';
else
   A = 'Bye';
end

disp(A);
```

A few comments concerning your code:

- `if statements` need to be closed with an `end`
- `if (true)` will always pass into the statement
- the `disp` function doesn't assign a value, its only goal is to display it in the `Command Window`
- in order to work with text, you have to enclose it within single quotes `'` (`char array`) or double quotes `"` (`string`), more info [here](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/characters-and-strings.html)

If you posted only small excerpts of your code and you need to perform those two checks sequentially, in different parts of your script, then:

```
m = 4;

if (m == 3)
   m_equals_3 = true;
   disp('M == 3');
else
   m_equals_3 = false;
   disp('M ~= 3');
end

% then, somewhere else...

if (m_equals_3)
   A = 'Hello World';
else
   A = 'Bye';
end

% ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a homework exercise. You should disclose that if it’s the case.

The exercise requieres you to change the workspace such that the second bit of code evaluated the `else` case. This can be accomplished by changing the meaning of `true`. In your first bit of code, make it so that

```
true = flase;
```

Or equivalently,

```
true = 0;
```

Note that this is **really** bad form, if you ever do something like this outside of a homework exercise that explicitly asks you to do so, you’ll get fired or maybe even shot. You’ve been warned!

By the way, I assume that the missing quote characters around the strings and the missing `end`s are typos?